# How to upload multiple image using retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit, multipartform-data

I have to upload multiple products information with images, each product have `name`, `quantity`, `price`, `image` (filePath) . and the products array will be send in `items` key .(please see the attached image)

[image]

> ProductModel

```
public class ProductModel  {

    private String itemName;
    private String itemDesc;
    private int  qty = 1;
    private String itemImage;


    public String getItemImage() {
        return itemImage;
    }

    public void setItemImage(String itemImage) {
        this.itemImage = itemImage;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty) {
        this.qty = qty;
    }

    public String getItemDesc() {
        return itemDesc;
    }

    public void setItemDesc(String itemDesc) {
        this.itemDesc = itemDesc;
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public void setItemName(String itemName) {
        this.itemName = itemName;
    }

}
```

Please help me to send request to server.

Comment: see https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Answer (score 0):

You must use `MultipartBody.Part` to upload multiple images using retrofit. Try this code:

```
public interface WebServicesAPI { 
    @Multipart
    @POST("url")
    Call<YourModel> upload(@Part MultipartBody.Part name, @Part MultipartBody.Part desc, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
}
```

Here is the method for uploading the files.

```
    private void upload() {
       MultipartBody.Part name= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("name", productModel.getName());
       MultipartBody.Part desc= MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("desc", productModel.getDesc());
       File propertyImageFile = new File(productModel.getPropertyImagePath());
        RequestBody propertyImage = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), propertyImageFile);
        MultipartBody.Part propertyImagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", propertyImageFile.getName(), propertyImage);

        final WebServicesAPI webServicesAPI = RetrofitManager.getInstance().getRetrofit().create(WebServicesAPI.class);
        Call<UploadSurveyResponseModel> response = null;

        response = webServicesAPI.upload(name, desc, propertyImagePart);

        response.enqueue(this);
    }
```